# instantiateViewController: trying to open new view

Tags: ios, swift3, ios10

I'm trying open new view

ViewController.swift
   -> InAppBrowserController.swift

Main.storyboard -> InAppBrowser View make & Storyboard Id -> Ok.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let nextViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InAppBrowserView") as! InAppBrowserController
self.present(nextViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Blockquote
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   2016-11-24 20:24:50.569000 GMK SWork[5920:2148780] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your storyboard you must set the identifier for UIViewController, before you can get in this way:

```
let yourController = UIStoryboard.init(name: @"yourStoryboardName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourVCIdentifier") as? UIViewController
```

is important to set the identifier (I think that your controller not found for this)

[image]

in any case if you not have special needs, you should use the 'segue' directly from the storyboard and push/present your controller with:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourVCIdentifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: I have already tried it
but it has helped me a lot.
Thank you!~

Answer (score 0):

```
 let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 if let controller = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "InAppBrowserView") as? InAppBrowserController {  
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        print("Controller not found")
    }
```

Write the safe code as above and make sure you have added the Identifier in the storyboard and assigned the class properly to the view controller else it will return nil.